# Slider de imagenes con css

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.slider {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.slider ul {
  width: 400%;
  /* mas imagenes mayor el % 100+*/
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  order: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s;
  animation: slider 20s infinite;
}

.slider ul li img {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
  order: 2;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: .7;
}

#sbutton1+label {
  background: url(http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/141001144835-innovative-cities-philly-1024x576.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sbutton2+label {
  background: url(https://b.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/coexist/imagecache/1280/poster/2012/11/1680856-poster-1280-10-smartest-european-cities-shutterstock-78340003-1.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sbutton3+label {
  background: url(http://www.worldatlas.com/r/w728-h425-c728x425/upload/d9/63/b0/most-populous-cities-in-oceania.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sbutton4+label {
  background: url(http://media.cntraveler.com/photos/57adedf97516fb180520de91/16:9/w_1024,c_limit/friendliest-burlington-GettyImages-157614212.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sbutton1:checked~ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  animation: none;
}

#sbutton2:checked~ul {
  margin-left: -100%;
  animation: none;
}

#sbutton3:checked~ul {
  margin-left: -200%;
  animation: none;
}

#sbutton4:checked~ul {
  margin-left: -300%;
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0%,
  20% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  25%,
  40% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  45%,
  70% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  72%,
  100% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton1" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton2" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton3" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton4" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton4"></label>

  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/141001144835-innovative-cities-philly-1024x576.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://b.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/coexist/imagecache/1280/poster/2012/11/1680856-poster-1280-10-smartest-european-cities-shutterstock-78340003-1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.worldatlas.com/r/w728-h425-c728x425/upload/d9/63/b0/most-populous-cities-in-oceania.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://media.cntraveler.com/photos/57adedf97516fb180520de91/16:9/w_1024,c_limit/friendliest-burlington-GettyImages-157614212.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

como puedo adaptar el `width` de cada imagen al 100% y el `height` al 100% de igual forma es decir que solo la parte de las miniaturas quede en la parte de abajo y las imagenes ocupen toda la pantalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero tienes que resetear márgenes y rellenos que los navegadores agregan por defecto en algunas etiquetas. Por ejemplo, `ul` por defecto tiene un padding izquierdo. Una manera rápida de resetear estos valores es:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Segundo, no es necesario darle un ancho de `400` pixeles a la lista; basta con darle `100%`. Además, el overflow lo debe tener el padre (`.slider`) ya que estás moviendo la lista, y no los elementos `li`.

Tercero, la propiedad `background-size`aplica a elementos que tienen una imagen **de fondo**, es decir, mediante `background-image`. Para hacer que un elemento `img` tenga las dimensiones del padre, basta con darle un `height` y `width` del `100%`.

Lo más complicado de hacer aquí son los thumbnails, ya que deben tener un contraste superior al del slider. Por ello, en el ejemplo que te pongo he creado un capa que oscurezca el slider al hacer hover sobre él, y acto seguido, se muestran los thumbnails.

**Ejemplo (ver en pantalla completa)**

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider ul {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  //overflow: hidden;
  order: 1;
  transition: all 0.9s;
  animation: slider 20s infinite;
}

.slider ul li {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider ul li img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  bottom: 50px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
  left: calc(50% - 90px);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  order: 2;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 3;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: .7;
}

#sbutton1+label {
  background: url(http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/141001144835-innovative-cities-philly-1024x576.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

#sbutton2+label {
  background: url(https://b.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/coexist/imagecache/1280/poster/2012/11/1680856-poster-1280-10-smartest-european-cities-shutterstock-78340003-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
}

#sbutton3+label {
  background: url(http://www.worldatlas.com/r/w728-h425-c728x425/upload/d9/63/b0/most-populous-cities-in-oceania.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  left: calc(50% - -30px);
}

#sbutton4+label {
  background: url(http://media.cntraveler.com/photos/57adedf97516fb180520de91/16:9/w_1024,c_limit/friendliest-burlington-GettyImages-157614212.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  left: calc(50% - -90px);
}

#sbutton1:checked~ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  animation: none;
}

#sbutton2:checked~ul {
  margin-left: -100%;
  animation: none;
}

#sbutton3:checked~ul {
  margin-left: -200%;
  animation: none;
}

#sbutton4:checked~ul {
  margin-left: -300%;
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0%,
  20% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  25%,
  40% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  45%,
  70% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  72%,
  100% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.slider:hover > input[type="radio"] + label {
  opacity: 1 ;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton1" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton2" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton3" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="sbutton4" name="sradio">
  <label for="sbutton4"></label>

  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/141001144835-innovative-cities-philly-1024x576.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://b.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/coexist/imagecache/1280/poster/2012/11/1680856-poster-1280-10-smartest-european-cities-shutterstock-78340003-1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.worldatlas.com/r/w728-h425-c728x425/upload/d9/63/b0/most-populous-cities-in-oceania.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://media.cntraveler.com/photos/57adedf97516fb180520de91/16:9/w_1024,c_limit/friendliest-burlington-GettyImages-157614212.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: pero se desaparen las miniaturas, las necesito, y como dije, las necesito en toda la pantalla.

Comment: No me di cuenta de ellas. ¿Por qué no pones un código **ejecutable**? Sube tus imágenes a imgur y pon las URLs en las `img`, luego actualiza tu pregunta y pon el nuevo código para que se pueda reproducir aquí directamente y sea más fácil darse cuenta del problema.

Comment: ya checaste el problema?, he visto que lo has actualizado muchas gracias.

Comment: Sí, ya estoy haciendo pruebas con el nuevo código. Espera mi actualización.

Comment: Listo, respuesta actualizada. Checka si es el efecto que deseas.

Comment: Muchas gracias gustavo por tomarte tu tiempo ayudarme. Saludos!